# How to enable/disable an input field using knockout js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

What i actually want is that if selectedPropertyType is title insurance only, then just disable that input field, i.e "title_servies_fee"

```
this.title_service_fee = ko.computed(function(){

            if(this.selectedPropertyType() == 'purchase') {

                return 200;

            }

            else if(this.selectedPropertyType() == 'cash-purchase') {

                return 200;

            }

            else if(this.selectedPropertyType() == 'refinance') {

                return 150;

            }

            else if(this.selectedPropertyType() == 'title-insurance-only') {

                return 200;

            }

            else {

                // here i want to disable the "title_service_fee" input field

            }

        }, this);
```

Comment: But this fieles is computed, so unless you make it writable it shouldn't be bound to an input. Apart from this, to make the input read only you need another computed that test your condition and return false when read only condition is reached and bound this new computed to "enable" binding of the input field

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. That's worked for me

Comment: Ok so I will add it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `data-bind` attribute to your `input` element like this:

```
<input data-bind="disable: selectedPropertyType() === 'title-insurance-only'" />
```

More information [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/disable-binding.html).

Answer (score 1):

This field is computed, so unless you make it writable it shouldn't be bound to an input.

Apart from that, to make the input read only you need another computed that test your condition and return false when read only condition is reached and bound this new computed to "enable" binding of the input field.